# Some zsh keybinds no longer work after reboot

Tags: arch-linux, zsh

After rebooting I've encountered this strange issue where some zsh keybinds like CTRL-A and CTRL-E don't work, instead printing `^A` and `^E` respectively.

Other keybindings like CTRL-U work fine. I'm sure this is a problem with zsh and not my terminal (urxvt) because i can launch bash and the keybindings work fine. I doubt my .zshrc is the problem either as I regularly close and reopen terminals, therefore reloading the config.

The last thing I did before the reboot was compile the kernel. It did not execute so I reverted back to the known working kernel. I highly doubt the corrupted kernel had anything to do with it because it failed to load way before anything in userspace happened.

##### Relevant `bindkey` output

```
"^A"-"^C" self-insert
...
"^E"-"^F" self-insert
...
"^U" vi-kill-line
...
```

Comment: It looks like you have `vi` bindings enabled (`bindkey -v` or `setopt vi`), I think this is unintentional?

Comment: @MartinTournoij That fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the line editor is configured to use the `vi` mode while you seem to be expecting the `emacs` mode.

In `zsh`, quoting the manual:

> If one of the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables
> contain the string 'vi' when the shell starts up then it will be
> 'viins', otherwise it will be 'emacs'.  bindkey's -e and -v options
> provide a convenient way to override this default choice.

So, here, add

```
bindkey -e
```

To your `~/.zshrc` to force `emacs` mode even when your preferred editor is `vi`/`vim`/`elvis`/`vimacs`...